# How to achieve a[1]+a[2], a[3]+a[4], a[5]+a[6] ........ using CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

I confuse on how to add adjacent 2 elements in an array, and stride is 2.

I don't know how to achieve this assignment.
Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: What problems did you face? Have you ever written a CUDA `__global__` function?

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
__global__ void add_pairs(float *in, float *out, size_t npairs){

  for (size_t idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x; idx < npairs; idx+=blockDim.x*gridDim.x) {
    float2 temp = (reinterpret_cast<float2 *>(in))[idx];
    out[idx] = temp.x+temp.y;}
}
```

Using a grid-stride loop, with vector load of the input

`npairs` is assumed to be the number of results to be generated - the number of pairs to be summed

the `in` pointer is assumed to be a properly `float2` aligned pointer

If you change each instance of `float` to e.g. `double` or `int`, and likewise for `float2`, it should work for other datatypes as well.

If you need additional help outside of the kernel code, e.g. with allocating device variables for example, I suggest studying a CUDA sample code, such as the `vectorAdd` sample code.